# IE9 Expected identifier, string or number error

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am getting the above error in in IE9 and I cannot see why this is happening. I have tried to find ways to troubleshoot this but am at a dead end. Can someone please point out where I have gone wrong. I thought at first it was the perhaps the last comma, but not the case. Thanks

jquery code

```
$.validator.setDefaults ({

        errorClass: 'form_error',
        errorElement: 'div'
    });

    $("#BA_boxform").validate({
        rules: {
            BA_customer: {
                required: true
            },
            customerdept: {
                required: true
            },
            customeraddress: {
                required: true
            },
            BA_service: {
                required: true
            },
            BA_box: {
                required: true
            },
            BA_destdate: {
                required: true
            },
            BA_authorised: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            BA_customer: {
                required: '<br />* required: You must select a customer'
            },
            customerdept: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must select a department"
            },
            customeraddress: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must select a customer address"
            },
            BA_service: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must select a service level"
            },
            BA_box: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must enter a box number for intake"
            },
            BA_destdate: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must enter a destruction date"
            },
            BA_authorised: {
                required: "<br />* required"
            } **<--- error is reported here**
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the trailing comma:

```
        } **<--- error is reported here**
    }, <--- problem is here
```

Comment: Why does this validation not work in IE7/8. It is fine in 9/10

Comment: @user1532468 Because IE7/8 treat invalid JSON differently than IE9+

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma in `messages` property. Last element in an array should not contain comma otherwise IE will throw an error.

```
$("#BA_boxform").validate({
   rules: {
      // rules
   },
   messages : {
      // messages.
   }, // REMOVE THE TRAILING COMMA
});
```

should be changed to

```
$("#BA_boxform").validate({
   rules: {
      // rules
   },
   messages : {
      // messages.
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
messages: {
            BA_customer: {
                required: '<br />* required: You must select a customer'
            },
            customerdept: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must select a department"
            },
            customeraddress: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must select a customer address"
            },
            BA_service: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must select a service level"
            },
            BA_box: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must enter a box number for intake"
            },
            BA_destdate: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must enter a destruction date"
            },
            BA_authorised: {
                required: "<br />* required"
            } **<--- error is reported here**
        }, // <- Problem is here
```

Remove last Comma.It should work fine.